# Git SubModule Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We're moving to Git. Now i've read everything which says don't use submodules with Git, however, I think it fits our purpose. We have shared libraries that need to be updated no matter which project they're in and then synced back to the server.

I've added the project to git, added a subproject and that all seems to work. However, a really weird thing happens, as soon as I save a file in visual studio that's part of the subproject, it no longer marks it as a change and I can no longer commit it or push it. It all works fine in the main project. It marks it as changed until the file is saved and then it disappears?

[image]

Any clues/tips would be really appreciated

Comment: PS: I see you have a git toolbar installed in your Visual Studio, which one is that, it's not the one that ships with Visual Studio, is it? It may interfere with standard features.

Answer (score 18):

There is a request in VisualStudio UserVoice to allow [Commit changes to a submodule using VS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519/suggestions/13316574), the request specifies the following:

> The same features that we have for files in GIT repositories should be
> available for files in submodules, too:
>
> - being able to commit changes to the submodule
> - current branch, pending changes and unpublished commits being displayed at bottom on VS window
> - mini-info about the file (n changes | n authors, n changes)
> - view history / annotate / compare with unmodified
> - etc.

If you also want these features to be implemented please vote [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519/suggestions/13316574) so it will get prioritized

Comment: looks that someone at MS reduced the scope of this request, if you want to see full git submodule support here is a new feature request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/19733674-full-git-submodule-support

Comment: This appears to now mostly have been implemented in Visual Studio 2017 Update 5 See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2017/2019 doesn't support submodules.** 
Download Visual Studio **2022** CTP and activate the preview of git submodules. 
Then see if it works with that.