# git sub modules visual studio 2017 not downloading

Tags: git, visual-studio

We have started to make use of `git submodules` as a way to reuse common code across projects

We have a simple rule at work, when people `get` your code it should `build` first time and your code should build on visual online without to much fuss.

If I add shared code via a `git submodule` then in order to build it first time we need to run

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

and to update

```
git submodule update --update --recursive
```

**Can I avoid the need to run the above commands?** **can VS be configured to pull the sub modules?**

I have looked to see if a nuget package is available that adds this is a build step.

Interestingly visual studio online will pull a git sub module via its advanced settings

[image]

git modules and VS are disucsseed in [Git SubModule Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502671/git-submodule-visual-studio) but its not quite the same issue, just very *basic support* would be a good start.

Comment: "git submodule update --update --recursive" didn't work, but "git submodule update --recursive", mean - remove the --update